# Strange syntax specification for python decorators

Tags: python, annotations, decorator, grammar

The syntax specification for [function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
funcdef        ::=  [decorators] "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ["->" expression] ":" suite
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [parameter_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
dotted_name    ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    | "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter]
                    | "**" parameter
                    | defparameter [","] )
parameter      ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
funcname       ::=  identifier
```

Seems to suggest the following is syntactically valid:

```
@some.dotted.name(*what : "is this")
def my_func(x):
    pass
```

Yet it is not accepted by the interpreter. Am I misreading the grammar, or is the grammar incorrect?

Comment: Suspect this is a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue27042 - only python 3 makes this claim

Comment: I put a reference to the erroneous patch into my answer, now that I had the time to track it down. I also point out that the grammar itself (i.e. the input to the parser generator) was not changed, and definitely says arglist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a documentation bug to me.

It was

```
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
```

until v3.2, when `argument_list` changed to `parameter_list`. That cannot be right, although whoever submitted the [one-line patch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/71ff2235bb4c) evidently thought otherwise.

The [grammar itself](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/grammar.html) was not modified. It still says:

```
decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
```

And since that is:

> the full Python grammar, as it is read by the parser generator and used to parse Python source files

I think we can conclude that Python decorators still have the syntax we all expect.

Comment: Nice job finding the patch!